# Change php mysql to php mssql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

Hey Everyone hope all well. I have this code that works perfectly on a mysql database

```
<?php
// visit http://php.net/pdo for more details
// start error handling

try 
{
  // connect
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=name', 'name', 'password');
  // enable error handling through exceptions
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  // create safe query
  $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT ip FROM tester WHERE state = ? ORDER BY RAND

(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())) LIMIT 1");

  // pass data & execute query (since the data are of string type
  // and therefore can be passed in this lazy way)
  $query->execute(array($_POST['State']));
  // get value
  $ip = $query->fetchColumn();
  // print out the IP address using $ip
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
  echo "sorry, there was an error.";
  mail("email@gmail.com", "database error", $e->getMessage(), "From: email@gmail.com");
}

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "email@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "This is a test";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['what']) ||
        !isset($_POST['State']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $what = $_POST['what']; // required
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $state = $_POST['State']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "What: ".clean_string($what)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "State: ".clean_string($ip)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";
// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
if (!mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers))
{
    echo "failed to send message";
}  

?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
?>
```

When someone selects a state and submits the web form, this code connects to the mysql database and

selects an ip address randomly and sends it to my email. It is perfect.

The problem i have is that the person i am doing this for does not want to use a mysql database so wants it

intergrated in a mssql database.

I know in the php code above that i am connecting to a mysql database instead of a mssql database but

can not work out what needs to be changed to make it all work.

I did find this online and thought i might be able to intergrate it with my exsisting code but so far no luck.

```
<?php
$myServer = "localhost";
$myUser = "your_name";
$myPass = "your_password";
$myDB = "examples"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 

//select a database to work with
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
  or die("Couldn't open database $myDB"); 

//declare the SQL statement that will query the database
$query = "SELECT id, name, year ";
$query .= "FROM cars ";
$query .= "WHERE name='BMW'"; 

//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mssql_query($query);

$numRows = mssql_num_rows($result); 
echo "<h1>" . $numRows . " Row" . ($numRows == 1 ? "" : "s") . " Returned </h1>"; 

//display the results 
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<li>" . $row["id"] . $row["name"] . $row["year"] . "</li>";
}
//close the connection
mssql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

Any help in getting this to work would be much appreciated. Thanks Everyone

Ali

Comment: your using mysql functions in your sql. You should adjust them. (the rand is mysql and not sql)

Comment: Can you post any errors you are getting?

Comment: Post the error you received, and indicate the line it was pointing to that triggered the error so we can look further

Comment: The error I receive in my email is 

Database error could not find driver

Also Bram, how can i make it pick up random ip if i take the ORDER BY RAND. Thanks everyone for all your help

Comment: Rand()  should work, but you will need to use `SELECT TOP 1` instead of `ORDER BY RAND() Limit 1`.  You will probably also need to change unix_timestamp(now()). If you're going to be doing this often then I can highly recommend SQL Cookbook published by O'Reilly, it really helped me out for such situations when I was migrating between databases

Comment: Database error could not find driver - Does mssql show up in your php_info() ? Are you on windows or linux? Should you use sqlsrv_ instead of mssql_ ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you didn't  enable the **MSSQL**   extension in `php.ini` file.

**In Linux**

- You will find this in **php.ini** file :      `;extension=mssql.so`
  and replace with this :   `extension=mssql.so`( just remove the
  semicolon to enable.)
- You will find a file in (if you are using xampp linux)
  lampp/etc/freetds.conf file. In this file you need to add the following configuration.

  add this:

  [DevSqlServer]

  host = 172.16.1.123

  instance = DEVAPSERVER

  port = 1433

  tds version = 7.0
- Restart your server. and your php code should be like this.
- Here you can  see what i have done. **DevSqlSerrver** i have given in
  the freetds.cof. So i need to give the server name that what i have
  given in freetds.conf.

  ```
    // Connect to MSSQL
     $connection = mssql_connect("DevSqlServer", 'sa', '****');
     $db_connect=mssql_select_db("DBname",$connection);
  ```

And you can access MSSQL Server database.

For more info:

[Link1](http://www.dotvoid.com/2010/01/adding-support-for-ms-sql-server-to-php-in-linux/)

[Link2](http://kmaiti.blogspot.in/2010/08/how-to-install-mssql-php-extension-on.html)